# Find a missing value or a different one in Excel between 2 couple of 2 columns

Tags: comparison, compare, excel-formula, rows

I have a Excel table with 4 columns, something like this :

```
      A       B       C       D

11    Id    Value    Id2    Value2
12    2       10      2       10
13    4       11      4       11
14    1       100     1       10
```

and I'd like to compare the id and value with the id2 and value2 to find out if there is any typed error of a value that corresponds to the id,

In this case the value2 with the corresponding id2 "1", D14, is wrong because on the row A14 dhe value that corresponds to the id 1 is 100, I have to do this for something like 2000 rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On cell E2 type this:
`=IF(CONCATENATE(A2;B2)=CONCATENATE(C2;D2);"OK";"ERROR")`
If it doesnt work try replacing ; with ,
It should work
Regards,